# Can a batch file, run a console exe that returns/prints a string to the command line and take them as a parameter in the .bat?

Tags: batch-file, command

How would I/can I from a batch file, run simple console exe that returns/prints a string of 4 numbers to the command. line and take them as a parameter in the .bat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming `consoleapp` prints four space-delimited numbers on one line:

  ```
  @echo off
  for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('consoleapp') do (
      echo arg1: %%a, arg2: %%b, arg3: %%c, arg4: %%d
  )
  pause
  ```
- No delimiters, just the 4 digits:

  ```
  @echo off
  for /f %%a in ('consoleapp') do set digits=%%a
  set digit1=%digits:~0,1%
  set digit2=%digits:~1,1%
  set digit3=%digits:~2,1%
  set digit4=%digits:~3,1%
  echo arg1: %digit1%, arg2: %digit2%, arg3: %digit3%, arg4: %digit4%
  pause
  ```

Comment: Hello mate, the theory of that looks perfect but I can't figure out why it isn't working. When I run it it just echos the batch files contents (your script above).

The string I'm using isn't space delimited it's like "1234". Could that be it? I tried the .exe as "test.exe" and as "test". Can you recommend a good batch file ide? I've never wrote enough of them to justify getting one setup! either way thanks for your efforts!

Comment: 1. Updated the code. 2. I don't know any batch-file IDE, the syntax is simple once you actually make an effort to learn it.